# my ubuntu freeze on shutdown and restart and suspend

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, freeze

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop .it freeze on reboot and shutdown and suspend and I have to manually shutdown with power key for turning off the computer. I tried https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia#Installation
the solution with no luck . can anybody help me?
I have n552vw laptop with i7 6700hq with the 960gt Nvidia driver

here is `sudo blkid` output:

```
/dev/sda2: UUID="148a4a5d-60cf-414e-8ce3-b79f86ad386c" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="a4dabba3-3ec9-4fe0-bcd8-fdb26e33d980"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: UUID="6BF5-CC22" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="4b160ac6-a5d2-4f8c-81c9-b02cc025d0cd"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="New Volume" UUID="7C7A8BDF7A8B9514" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="99a61984-cdc3-477d-9c2b-20b5eff5a457"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop12: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop13: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop14: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop15: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop16: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop17: TYPE="squashfs"
```

here is /etc/fstab:

```
  /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=148a4a5d-60cf-414e-8ce3-b79f86ad386c /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
#UUID=6BF5-CC22  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=6BF5-CC22  /boot/efi   vfat    defaults    0   1
```

here is free -h

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.7G        5.4G        418M        230M        1.9G        1.8G
Swap:          2.0G          0B        2.0G
```

and last one `cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`

```
cat: /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume: No such file or directory
```

`sudo fdisk -l` output

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 3.7 MiB, 3878912 bytes, 7576 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 13 MiB, 13619200 bytes, 26600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 34.6 MiB, 36216832 bytes, 70736 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 13 MiB, 13619200 bytes, 26600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 1.2 MiB, 1253376 bytes, 2448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 140.9 MiB, 147722240 bytes, 288520 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 2.3 MiB, 2355200 bytes, 4600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 14.5 MiB, 15196160 bytes, 29680 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 119.2 GiB, 128035676160 bytes, 250069680 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 6270DE80-FEA1-4548-BE07-17C506FCAD06

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624 250068991 249018368 118.8G Linux filesystem




Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 5D1C00F9-28BD-4FF1-9DAF-FC6D770E1A49

Device     Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 1953523711 1953521664 931.5G Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/loop8: 53.7 MiB, 56311808 bytes, 109984 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop9: 140.7 MiB, 147496960 bytes, 288080 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop10: 34.7 MiB, 36323328 bytes, 70944 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop11: 2.3 MiB, 2433024 bytes, 4752 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop12: 3.7 MiB, 3887104 bytes, 7592 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop13: 238.6 MiB, 250220544 bytes, 488712 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop14: 91.1 MiB, 95494144 bytes, 186512 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop15: 89.5 MiB, 93835264 bytes, 183272 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop16: 14.5 MiB, 15208448 bytes, 29704 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop17: 91 MiB, 95408128 bytes, 186344 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

here is my additional driver i chose:
[image]

here is a screenshot of what happening after waking up in suspend state.

[image]
and here is `snap list` output

```
Name                     Version         Rev   Tracking  Publisher   Notes
core                     16-2.37.1       6350  stable    canonical✓  core
core18                   18              677   stable    canonical✓  base
gnome-3-26-1604          3.26.0          74    stable/…  canonical✓  -
gnome-calculator         3.30.1          260   stable/…  canonical✓  -
gnome-characters         3.30.0          139   stable/…  canonical✓  -
gnome-logs               3.30.0          45    stable/…  canonical✓  -
gnome-system-monitor     3.30.0          57    stable/…  canonical✓  -
gtk-common-themes        0.1-4-g88bc1b2  818   stable/…  canonical✓  -
kde-frameworks-5-core18  5.54.0          26    stable    kde✓        -
ktouch                   18.12.1         27    stable    kde✓        -
```

Note: my laptop has Skylake Cpu(i7 6700HQ) which won't support with Linux kernel and it will stick in logo after installing ubuntu... after struggling to resolve this issue I come up with adding Nouveau in grub configuration and I managed to login in ubuntu eventually and now I have this problem.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89753/discussion-on-question-by-mohammad-khalifeh-my-ubuntu-freeze-on-shutdown-and-res).

Answer (score 1):

I have been in your position partly where my computer started freezing on suspending after installing Nvidia Drivers. Nvidia drivers are known to create several problems in the computers, hence I don't recommend until you are sure that that's not the reason behind the issue.

I solved my problem by re-installing the default drivers (X.org). You could try the same.
X.org drivers can be reinstalled by selecting the same from the Additional Drivers menu in your Ubuntu

[image: Additional Drivers menu in my distro]

or following these [steps](https://gist.github.com/erikvip/0e46a6d9ad742c81d148) through your terminal.

Comment: You can also refer here - https://askubuntu.com/a/56872/801564

Comment: This is a very bad answer. Your experience is contrary of that of the most users.

Comment: Hello @GabrielaGarcia, I appreciate your opinion. I will delete the answer it doesn't contribute towards solving the problem of the person who asked it.

Comment: There was never a case when nouveau works better than the proprietary drivers. It may work roughly the same for older chips but due to its unofficial/community driven nature it always lags behind the manufacturer's drivers. The current generation of high-end chips has poor support or no support at all (no video) by nouveau. Performance, features, ports, etc. in new chips always require the Nvidia drivers to work at its full potential. If there are issues when using the Nvidia drivers it needs troubleshoot, other than reverting to nouveau.

Comment: @VipulGupta Thanks for your response i tried it ,and it wont fix my suspend problem but it fix my reboot and shutdown problem... but it won't take long it will be back after some day.. i don't know what cause it.

Comment: Well, @Mohammadkhalifeh do let me know if it comes back. I will delete the answer then. I wish I had a better fix than this. It worked for me and several others I tried it on, and that's why I posted. Happy to help more. For suspend problem, you can try digging through other answers or try out a different version of the Kernel by selecting it from the BIOS (If everything else fails)

Comment: @VipulGupta Thank you. my problem exists yet. but my reboot and shut down problem solved with Nvidia 415 Driver. but my suspend problem continued.